# Propagate edits to a txt file all the way back in repo history

Tags: git

I've edited a txt file with a wanted change and pushed change on the master branch.

How would I propagate the change I did in this file all the way back in history to when the file was created.

If it's possible to do this and how would I execute this?

Comment: You cannot change the original commits. Neither can Git: once made, *every* commit is read-only. What you *can* do is make a new "history"—a new series of commits in which the file always looked the way you wanted—and then try to convince not only yourself, but also everyone else, to stop using the old commits and start using the new-and-improved commits instead. How many Git repositories have the *old* commits? How eager are their owners to switch over to your new history? The answer to that question tells you whether you should bother with all of this.

Comment: If you decide that it *is* worth doing, then there are multiple ways to do it. Which to use depends on multiple things, such as how many commits you need to swap out for new-and-improved versions. One way is to use rebase, as in [Pistanic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60012609/1256452). Another is to use `git filter-branch`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git: rewrite history: reorder and merge commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626642/git-rewrite-history-reorder-and-merge-commits)

Answer (score 0):

One Method would be to use git Rebase.
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Check out a new branch and revert it to the desired file. 
Rebase the changes from your "master" to the desired file.

Comment: will this update the file throughout whole of the history of repo? If someone was to checkout specific commit, will they see the old content of the file or the new one? I know about rebase, but I did not know that it could do what I want to do in my original question.

Comment: I tried interactive rebase, it did not go back in the history. It took commits from back in history and after I was done with editing and interactive rebase it just laid all of it on top of my master branch. Old files where not touched or updated in anyway and history expanded. I've done this on a test branch not to destroy my original repo.

Comment: I think that I had misunderstood your question... You want changes from head commit to be applied to the file state all the way down the tree? -- If that is the case then I do not understand your end goal or why this is a desirable outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [git-filter-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) or [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) to rewrite the history. But these require to write some shell scripts around.

I have wrote several to ease the usage.
Personally I prefer the `git-filter-branch` as the `git-filter-repo` is not convenient for a regexp text replace out of the box (file text replace is not the same as file replace).

https://github.com/andry81/tacklelib/tree/HEAD/bash/tacklelib/tools/git/git_filter_branch_update_file_text.sh

```bash
# Usage:
#   git_filter_branch_update_file_text.sh [<flags>] [//] <dir> <file-name-pattern> <text-to-match> <text-to-replace> [<cmd-line>]

# Examples:
#   # To update all commits in all heads to update first commit(s) in all
#   # ancestor branches.
#   >
#   cd myrepo/path
#   git_filter_branch_update_file_text.sh . README.md '<p/>' '</p>' -- --all
#
#   # To update all commits by tag `t1` to update first commit(s) in all
#   # ancestor branches.
#   >
#   cd myrepo/path
#   git_filter_branch_update_file_text.sh . README.md '<p/>' '</p>' -- t1
#
#   # To update single commit by a tag (excluding all parents).
#   >
#   cd myrepo/path
#   git_filter_branch_update_file_text.sh . README.md '<p/>' '</p>' -- t1 --not t1^@
#
#   # To update master branch commits excluding tags.
#   >
#   cd myrepo/path
#   git_filter_branch_update_file_text.sh . README.md '<p/>' '</p>' -- master ^t1 ^t2
#
#   # Remove multiline text with mixed line returns
#   >
#   cd myrepo/path
#   git_filter_branch_update_file_text.sh -E . changelog.txt '2023\.05\.23:\r?\n[^\r\n]+\r?\n' '' -- master ^t1 ^t2
```

This will update file text in all filtered commits.

You are require to anchor your changes with some text around the changes. If anchor text is not found, then the file would be **silently** skipped to change. So this is not as simple as may look at first time.