# How to Push an open-source template to Github without the commits history?

Tags: git, github, repository, version, clone

I started working the development of a CRM and, to avoid reinventing the wheel, started building on top of a free open-source MUI template.

However, it's evident that I need to version control and maintain it in a GitHub repository. The issue is that when I pushed, as expected, the entire commit history and everything related to the template came with it, what I dont want to.

Is there any way to remove all the commits and contributors?

I appreciate the assistance and hope my question wasn't confusing.

PS: I just figured out, just made rm -rf .git to remove completely the current directory after cloning, then just make a new repository start from it. thats it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To rearrange old commits with Git and push the new history to the origin, follow these steps:

1. Make a backup of your branch in case anything goes wrong. `git branch backup-branch`
2. Use the interactive rebase command to reorder your commits, e.g. reorder the last 4 commits `git rebase -i HEAD~4`
3. Reorder the commits by changing the order of the lines. You can also squash or fixup commits by replacing the "pick" command with "squash" or "fixup" respectively.
4. Git will apply the changes and create a new commit history based on your reordering.
5. Once you're satisfied with the new commit history, you can push it to the origin repository using the force push command: `git push -f origin branch-name`. Note that force pushing will overwrite the remote branch history.

Additional links:

- [Reordering of commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740537/reordering-of-commits)
- [how to re-order commits in Git non-interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981061/how-to-re-order-commits-in-git-non-interactively)
- [git: rewrite history: reorder and merge commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626642/git-rewrite-history-reorder-and-merge-commits)